# Regex capturing moveable groups

Tags: java, regex

How can I capture groups that can change place? For example, if I have a command that contains a file name and a folder name I want a regex that can capture both the name and folder name for both of these commands:

```
--name "name" --folderName "folderName"

--folderName "folderName" --name "name"
```

I can write something like this:

```
"(--name (?<name>\w+) --folderName (?<folderName>\w+))|(--folderName (?<folderName>\w+) --name (?<name>\w+))"
```

But this is obviously very long and it would be much longer if I had more than 2 groups. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Just capture the generic pattern `--option "value" --option "value" ...` to get the list of options.  After that, you can test the option names and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:`"(?<=--name \")[^\"]+|(?<=--folderName \")[^\"]+"`

Test here: https://regex101.com/r/ipMitv/1